# OnClicks links to wrong button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to link the button across every row to delete that row when clicked. However, every delete button is linked to the onclick delete of the last created row.

For example:

**TABLE**

Record 1 | deleteButton1

Record 2 | deleteButton2

Record 3 | deleteButton3

**Actions:**

*clicks deleteButton1* ---> *deletes the row with "Record 3"*

*clicks deleteButton1* ---> *tries to delete the row with "Record 3"* (a.k.a. nothing happens b/c row not found)

*clicks deleteButton2* ---> *tries to delete the row with "Record 3"* (a.k.a. nothing happens b/c row not found)

HTML:

```
<table id="Table"></table>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Code snippet
for (var x = 0; x < itemArray.length; x++) 
{
    selectedItem = itemArray[x];
    table = document.getElementById("Table");
    row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = selectedItem;
    cell2.innerHTML = "<button>—</button>";  //Delete button across every row.
    cell2.onclick = function () { removeRow(selectedItem); };
}

function removeRow(content, where) 
{ 
            var table;

            table = document.getElementById("Table");

            var iter;

            for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) 
            {
                iter = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;

                if (iter == content)
                {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: should `<id="Table">` be `<table id="Table">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `onclick` function references the variable `selectedItem`. After your `for` loop, that variable is set to the last item in the array. So, every button will reference that last item. [Here is a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3d4Bc/).

I suggest using Javascript's [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) and [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) to allow a button to reference its own parent row.

In my example below, `rowIndex` returns the index number of the `tr` that is the `parentNode` for the clicked cell (`td`). This index number can be used to remove a table row directly.

```
cell2.onclick = function () {  removeRow(this.parentNode.rowIndex);  };

function removeRow(x) { 
    document.getElementById("Table").deleteRow(x);
}
```

[Working Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3d4Bc/1/)

Comment: Oooooooh! Makes sense! I expected JavaScript to make a copy of selectedItem into each of those onClicks b/c I thought "var selectedItem" will be destroyed after the for-loop like C#. But then, I read about closure in JavaScript which contradicts my ideology, so now I realize the power of learning programming language theory.

Comment: Also, your method really helped shorten my block of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this :

http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/170869-dynamically-add-delete-reorder-rows-table.html

Here :

```
       for (var i= startingIndex; i< tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {

            // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObject settings
            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.one.data = count; // text

            // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObject settings
            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.two.name = INPUT_NAME_FS; // input text
            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.two.id = INPUT_NAME_FS + count;

            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.three.name = INPUT_NAME_FS_DESIGN; // input text
            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.three.id = INPUT_NAME_FS_DESIGN + count;


            // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObj settings

            // CONFIG: requires class named classy0 and classy1
            tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].className = 'classy' + (count % 2);

            count++;
        }
```